# Compare and match the columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Column "A" is static and can't be change. I have to re-arrange column B to match it with column A. 
Column "C" is a part of column B and should be re-arranged accordingly. See the end result.

```
A   B   C
SGK LSP BAL BHARATI PUBLIC SCHOOL       
RNG KQN BAL BHAVAN INTERNATIONAL SCHOOL     
LSP SGK BASAVA INTERNATIONAL SCHOOL     
KQN LAK BGS INTERNATIONAL SCHOOL        
QEH HDY BRAIN INTERNATIONAL SCHOOL
    QEH BRAIN INTERNATIONAL SCHOOL
    RNG BRAIN INTERNATIONAL SCHOOL
```

I want the end result to be in this format:

```
A   B   C
SGK SGK BASAVA INTERNATIONAL SCHOOL     
RNG RNG BRAIN INTERNATIONAL SCHOOL
LSP LSP BAL BHARATI PUBLIC SCHOOL       
KQN KQN BAL BHAVAN INTERNATIONAL SCHOOL     
QEH QEH BRAIN INTERNATIONAL SCHOOL
    HDY BRAIN INTERNATIONAL SCHOOL
    LAK BGS INTERNATIONAL SCHOOL
```

What would be the formula for this? I have a thousand such files.

Comment: If all you need is to match column A with B, can you just set column A equals to column B? Or is there another reason why you need to match them? If col A exists for the pure purpose of match B, why bother with it?

Comment: How do I do that? Column A is mixed up and I need to match it with column B and corresponding column C. Yes, column A exists with respect to column B but it's not arranged accordingly.

Comment: maybe you can just sort columns B and C by [custom list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sort-data-using-a-custom-list-def8ff2b-681a-4fc3-9bd2-a06455c379e) where `Sort By` will be collumn B and `Order` will be custom list imported from the range in column A

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you properly, to solve this problem you will need to use the [VLookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) function.

1. Create a new spreadsheet
2. Copy the headers over
3. Copy all of column A
4. The formula for cell B2 would be `=A2`
5. The formula for cell C2 would be `=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet1!$B:$C, 2, false)`

Comment: No, You don't understand. Could you look at my question again and see the end-result? I want the end-result to be exactly that. Match A with B while C changes accordingly. Consider the columns B & C are together.

Comment: I've looked at your question and this is how I understand it.  Maybe you could rephrase or clarify.

Comment: I have edited the question. Is it making any better?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom list from your A column, then sort B:C according to that.

To create a custom list go to Excel > Options > Advanced > General >  <kbd>Edit Custom Lists...</kbd> > select as much of Column A as required, Import, OK, OK.

This is a application level setting, so available 'until further notice'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is as in the image below and you want result in `Column H` and `Column I`.

[image]

Enter the following formula in cell `H2`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,$B$2:$C$20,1,FALSE),IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$20,MATCH(0,IFERROR(MATCH($B$2:$B$20,$A$2:$A$20,0),COUNTIF($H$1:$H1,$B$2:$B$20)),0)),""))
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then in cell `I2`, enterthe following formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,$B$2:$C$20,2,FALSE),IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$20,MATCH(0,IFERROR(MATCH($B$2:$B$20,$A$2:$A$20,0),COUNTIF($H$1:$H1,$B$2:$B$20)),0)),""))
```

Again, this is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

***NOTE:-*** Result will not display names that are in `Column A` but not in `Column B`.

Second part of the formula is taken from [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/comparing-two-columns-of-names-and-returning/ea968fbe-ced3-4037-902a-f135a2baa1f7?page=1&tm=1319205278419&auth=1#footer).